# Restrict access control on RabbitMQ command line tool

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

I have a question related to secure the access control on RMQ

Here is a scenario: I am a windows admin account, I installed RMQ and add a new admin account in the management dashboard.

Now, it looks like any windows user without privileges, can run the command line tool and manage the existing users/queues, corrupting the data.

> rabbitmqctl add_user "newAdmin" "pa$$w0rd"

> rabbitmqctl delete_user "oldAdmin"

is there any protection mechanism or way to deny access? or restrict anyone to remove add users ?